# What is the purpose of a LinkedList in Java Considering an ArrayList Has No Size Limit?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linked-list, big-o

In many posts, when I read about the benefits of a LinkedList, the most frequent benefit I hear about is that in some situations a LinkedList is more performant because insertion and deletion is quicker than in an array.

Specifically, the argument is that arrays are less efficient to use because in order to expand them, it is necessary to copy the contents to a different array with a larger declared size.

However, since Java has the ArrayList, which does not have a capacity limit, this point about LinkedLists being more performant does not appear to be valid. Are LinkedLists now obsolete in Java? Are there any situations in which a LinkedList actually is still a better option than an ArrayList in Java?

Comment: "which does not have a capacity limit" - the ArrayList is still backed by an array, but it just hide the array expansion and copying for you.

Comment: Ever thought about _why_ `ArrayList` is called "_array_ list"? It uses an array under the hood.

Comment: You are right, you are unlikely to need a `LinkedList`  ever. I used one once in my 20+ years as a Java programmer and in retrospect regretted.

Comment: There seems to have been a tradition for using linked lists before Java, so I guess they thought then they’d better include one in the Java Collections Framework too. So if I’m right, the purpose was rather one of presenting what people will perceive as a full set of collection implementations. It was an easy way of avoiding criticism for a shortcoming no matter if that criticism would have been valid or not. The purpose was not a practical one.

Comment: The worst part is they're still used in tech interviews when interviewing candidates

Comment: For a tech interview what I wrote in my comments ought to be a good answer (or else I don’t want to work there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that you have a list with 100,000 (or some similarly large number) elements.

Say that you want to insert an element at the beginning, or somewhere in the middle.

With the ArrayList, you need to move *every single element* back by one place to make room. This requires `O(n)` operations, obviously.

With the LinkedList, you just need to create a new node and slot it in. If you already know where you need it, this is an `O(1)` operation.

Vice versa for deletion - especially as the list size gets larger, and as indexing becomes less important relative to insertion and deletion, linked lists have performance advantages over array lists.

And that's discounting how linked lists demonstrate concepts that are important for later extending to trees and graphs, from an educational perspective. But that's not what you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain that. Your answer really clarified that point for me.

Comment: For inserting in the beginning you clearly need to use `ArrayDeque`, not `LinkedList`. Even for inserting in the middle of a large list in some cases overall performance has been measured to be better with `ArrayList` since the `LinkedList` used in this way tends to spread over many more memory pages and hence cause thrashing.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of a LinkedList in Java considering an ArrayList has no size limit?

There are not many situations where a `LinkedList` is objectively better than an `ArrayList`.

First some basic facts:

- Both list types are dynamic in size (no difference).
- The `ArrayList` occupies less memory per element than an `LinkedList`.  By a factor of 4 or more.  (One pointer per element versus three pointers plus the overhead of a heap node.)
- If you grossly miss-estimate the initial capacity of an `ArrayList`, it can use more memory than a `LinkedList`.  (But that's really an application bug.)
- Most operations are faster for an `ArrayList`.

  - positional operations are `O(1)` versus `O(N)`
  - the performance effects of locality versus memory cache / TLB cache / VM page misses can be significant for large lists.
- Some operations can be faster for a `LinkedList`; e.g. insertion and deletion.   However, it depend on the specifics; e.g. the position of an insertion or deletion, or whether the operation triggers an expansion of the backing array.

---

So what are the cases where `LinkedList` is likely to be advantageous?

One case is adding and removing elements at the start of a list.  This is `O(1)` for a `LinkedList` and `O(N)` for an `ArrayList`.  (An `ArrayDeque` would typically be a better alternative than a `LinkedList` ... except that it doesn't implement the `List` API.)

A second case is traversing a list and adding or removing elements during the traversal.  The `LinkedList.listIterator` method returns a `ListIterator` that allows you to add or remove an element at the current position.  These are `O(1)` operations.

Thirdly, a `LinkedList` might conceivably be advantageous if your application is exceedingly intolerant of (for example) list appends that *might* take a long time.  (Think of hard realtime applications ....)

Finally, it is actually incorrect to say that an `ArrayList` has no size limit.  It is actually limited to slightly under 2^31 elements.  This is because Java arrays are limited to slightly under 2^31 elements by the JVM.  `LinkedList` does not have this problem.

---

> Are LinkedLists now obsolete in Java?

No.

The class is rarely used (and always has been), but it is not obsolete.

I recall that Brian Goetz has said that in retrospect it probably wasn't worth the effort to implement `LinkedList`.  But given that the effort was expended, you should feel free to use the class when this is warranted.

---

Note that you need to take account of all of the operations performed on a list.  This is often too difficult to do ahead of time.  And the (programmer) effort is frequently not justifiable.  Since `ArrayList` usually turns out to be the best choice, it is most programmer's default choice.

Avoid the trap of premature optimization....

Comment: *One case is adding and removing elements at the start of a list.* Don’t use `LinkedList` for this. Use `ArayDeque`. I mean, clearly.

Comment: Well ... yes ... but an `ArrayDeque` doesn't allow you to do **other** list operations.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList have an array inside it and in order to be dynamic it sometimes need to expand internal array.
[Internal Working of ArrayList in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-arraylist-in-java/amp/)

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList achieves unlimited capacity by automatically resizing itself when necessary. As such, it must still copy the elements to a new location. The only difference is that is done behind the scenes instead of requiring you, the programmer, to do so.